# How to simplify MSBuild-targets?

Tags: msbuild

```xml
<Target Name="ProtobufCompile"
        Inputs="@(ProtocCompile)"
        Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('%(ProtocCompile.RelativeDir)','\.\.[/\\]',''))%(ProtocCompile.Filename).cs">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <protooutdir>$(IntermediateOutputPath)$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('%(ProtocCompile.RelativeDir)','\.\.[/\\]',''))</protooutdir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="%(ProtocCompile.Filename)%(ProtocCompile.Extension)" Importance="high" />
  <MakeDir Directories="$(protooutdir)" />
  <Exec Command="$(ProtobufCompiler) --protoc_dir=${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}/.. --proto_path=%(ProtocCompile.RootDir)%(ProtocCompile.Directory) -output_directory=$(protooutdir) %(ProtocCompile.FullPath)" />
</Target>
<!-- set Intputs and Outputs -->
<Target Name="ProtobufCSharpCompile"
        DependsOnTargets="ProtobufCompile">
  <CreateItem Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('%(ProtocCompile.RelativeDir)','\.\.[/\\]',''))%(ProtocCompile.Filename).cs">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Compile"/>
  </CreateItem>
</Target>
<Target Name="ProtobufClean"
        BeforeTargets="Clean">
  <Delete Files="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('%(ProtocCompile.RelativeDir)','\.\.[/\\]',''))%(ProtocCompile.Filename).cs" />
</Target>
```

This is the piece of target-file. How to simplify this code? How to reduce duplicating of string below?

```xml
$(IntermediateOutputPath)$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('%(ProtocCompile.RelativeDir)','\.\.[/\\]',''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already specified a property for that value like so:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
  <protooutdir>$(IntermediateOutputPath)$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('%(ProtocCompile.RelativeDir)','\.\.[/\\]',''))</protooutdir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You can just replace references to that string with the property *$(protooutdir)* like so:

```
<CreateItem Include="$(protooutdir)%(ProtocCompile.Filename).cs">
```

and

```
<Delete Files="$(protooutdir)%(ProtocCompile.Filename).cs" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that $(protooutdir) is accessible in scope of <Target Name="ProtobufCompile">. Does all properties and items exist in global scope?

Comment: How to fix duplicating between property "protooutdir" and attribute "Outputs"?

Comment: I think that if you call the ProtobufCompile target before the other targets then those other targets will be able to access it. However you can always define the protooutdir property outside of the targets to make it global.